# what does 0 != do in this code?

Tags: c, obfuscation, deobfuscation

What does `0 !=` do in this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<8*5;i++)
        printf("%d",0 != ("HELLO"[i/8] & 1 << (~i&7)) );
    return 0;
}
```

This is a simple string to binary conversion. I understand the `` `("HELLO"[i/8] & 1 << (~i&7)) `` but I can't understand the `0 !=` part & if I remove it it doesn't work.

Is there any site which teaches bitwise operations in depth?

Comment: looks like after all you don't understand the second part...

Answer (score 6):

```
a != b
```

Is an expression that equates to true or false.  In C, there is no `true` and `false`, but rather 0 is considered false and anything else is considered true.  An expression such as `a != b` will return 0 if it's false, and 1 if it's true.  %d is the format string to print out an integer, so printf() will then print this 0 or 1.

In this context, a is 0 and b is the beast of an expression on the other side `("HELLO"[i/8] & 1 << (~i&7))`
To elaborate a bit on the other operations:

`("HELLO"[i/8] & 1 << (~i&7))` should have parenthesis added to make it clearer:

```
(("HELLO"[i/8]) & (1 << (~i&7)))
```

(~i&7) takes i, flips all of the bits in it, then ands all of the bits with the bits of 7.

```
(1 << (~i&7)))
```

Takes 1 and left shifts it ~i&7 places.

```
a & b
```

Takes `a` and `ANDS` all the bits with those in `b`.

A few links:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation

http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/bitwise_operators.html

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/17zwb64t.aspx

Comment: Also add: `0 != ("HELLO"[i/8] & 1 << (~i&7))` is actually a Boolean expression which evaluates to `true` or `false`. So the code will print 0 or 1.

Comment: @Hindol the first paragraph explains that quite in detail, though I guess I could add a little snippet to clarify

Comment: Thanks for the answer.i know bitwise operations but sometimes i just wonder how people find the "TRICKS" to get around something lengthy to simple one liner.